# POST to WebAPI controller results in null parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to POST a JSON string to a WebAPI controller that accepts a complex type as the parameter but all of the parameters properties are always null. Based on the code below, any ideas why? The request is hitting the WebAPI method properly and the parameter is not null, but all of it's properties are.

**EDIT:** If I remove the call to JSON.stringify(), the parameter properties are populated correctly, but my request body is now a querystring instead of a valid JSON object and this won't fly because my actual object also holds some sub-collections that don't work when passed as a querystring.

**Model**

```
public class SavedViewData
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int? SavedID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON Request Body** (copied from Fiddler)

```
{"UserID":"1","SavedID":null,"Name":"Test","Description":"Description"}
```

**WebAPI Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public int Save(SavedViewData viewData)
{
    return 1;
}
```

**jQuery $.ajax call**

```
var view = {
    UserID: userID,
    SavedID: null,
    Name: 'Test',
    Description: 'Description'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/save',
    data: JSON.stringify(view),
    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {    
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

Comment: Try sending `UserID` as a number instead of a string.

Comment: @Archer you have it wrong, content type is what you're sending and data type is what you're expecting.

Comment: Good catch on UserID, but changing it has no effect on the problem.

Comment: The URL is valid, can you use a breakpoint in the action `save`?

Comment: Yes, the URL is valid and I can hit breakpoints.

Comment: @Musa I should stop posting now.  It's been a long day :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So as I expected, it was something stupid:

```
contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

should have been

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

The "T" in type wasn't capitalized...there goes half a day!

Comment: I get tripped up on this exact issue a lot when using Fiddler for testing - remember to add 'Content-Type: application/json' to your composer headers!